# Compare value from cell after being rounded is not working

Tags: excel

I have a set up in Excel that compares the value of two cells. One with a low value and another where a user will type in a value. One of the cells then will change to green and say that it passed, or stay red and say fail. The problem I'm having is that I want to compare the value after it is rounded. 
For example let's say I have the formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E14),E14>=200),"PASS","FAIL")
```

and I type in `199.9`, the cell will show `200`, but it will fail in the other cell.  I have tried to use a ROUND function in the formula, but the Pass/Fail box will show `#VALUE!`.

Is there a way to compare the value in the cell after being rounded?

Comment: have you tried changing the number format to the cell where 199.9 is typed to number + 2 decimal places?

Comment: Please show the formula you have tried to use a round function in the formula but then it had returned #VALUE.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the actual value in the cell is 199.9. When the comparison is done it is comparing the 199.9 instead of the 200. I'm thinking about doing a VBA that will automatically round up the value when typed in, but that is just overkill.

Comment: Axel-  =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E14),(ROUND(E14,0))>=B14),"PASS","FAIL")

Comment: You could also turn the "precision as displayed" toggle on.

Comment: pnuts- Might be editing it so that it is VBA code. Haven't found a useful formula yet.

Comment: also, for what it's worth...the rounding formula you typed in the comments works for me when 200 is in B14 and E14 is 199.9 (formatted as a number and showing 0 decimals) returns PASS.  You'll get a #VALUE error if you have something like "FOO" typed in E14 or B14.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: sous2817 - Meant to explain it more but there is text in it that says Not Tested before value into cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your formula in your comments is fine, except when you have a text value in E14, which will then return a #VALUE error.

The problem is with this part: (ROUND(E14,0))>=B14. Step through the formula (FORMULAS => Formula Auditing => Evaluate Formula). You'll see the problem is that you're trying to round a text value that is in cell E14. This is probably overkill on nesting IF functions, but I think it will help you identify the issue:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E14),IF(ROUND(E14,0)>=B14,"PASS","FAIL"),"Doesn't Compare")
```

Put a 199.9 in E14 and it will return true (assuming 200 in B14).  Now put Foo in E14 and you'll see the "Doesn't Compare" message.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use semicolon instead of comma:
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E14);(ROUND(E14;0))>=B14);"PASS";"FAIL")

Comment: Would vote down for the semicolon, but vote up as the formula is correct if you use comma (if that's the locality setting) `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B14),ROUND(B14,0)>=200),"PASS","FAIL")`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: the `AND(ISNUMBER(B14),ROUND(B14,0)>=200)` is useless if `B14` is NaN. It then results in `AND(FALSE, #VALUE)` and this results in `#VALUE`. The only way is checking if NaN before further calculations as shown by sous2817.

Comment: Good point Axel. I should check my answers a tad more thoroughly. :)